# ReactNative - Transfer complex object from native code to JS code

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I wrote a native module in Android that needs to send data to my React Native JS code.

However, the data I wish to send is a complex model and isn't one of basic types (int, double, array, etc.).

Here is method in the native module:

```
@ReactMethod
public void getDeviceInfo(final Callback successCallback, final Callback errorCallback) {
    successCallback.invoke(new SomeComplexModel());
}
```

The application crashes (can't find any log) when trying to invoke the success method (same goes when trying to use Promises).

One way to tackle this problem is mapping the complex model into WriteableMap or something like that, but I'd prefer not to.

Do I have another choice?

I followed this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you displayed the error message and the details about the data structure. It would perform terribly, but you could always JSON.stringify() the structure and then JSON.parse() it on the other side (but this is basically what the serialization is doing).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find any log for the crash. The data structure isn't relevant because it seems you can't send any custom object -
As I understand, this is the design, but I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: As I understand, this is by design. You can send only basic data types from string, number, boolean, array (writeablearray) and object (writeablemap). For any complex datatype you need to build alternate structure. This would be helpful: https://medium.com/shoutem/ways-to-pass-objects-between-native-and-javascript-in-react-native-c3dcae7bf4f5